# Error when creating Trigger (PostgreSQL 9.4)

Tags: trigger, postgresql-9.4

I created a table 'Company', and I want to create a trigger so a company can only present in one city, but it can be present in several different cities in the same country. For example, there's only one company A (com_id 1) in NYC, but at the same time company A(com_id 2) can be present in Washington, so in US there are two company A(com_id 1 & 2). It is not allowed to have com_id 1 & 2 both be present in NYC.

So I found this page and worte my code as this: [enter link description here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Deleting_duplicates)

```
    CREATE TABLE "Company"
(
  com_id integer NOT NULL,
  com_name character(50) NOT NULL,
  city character(50) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT com_pk PRIMARY KEY (com_id),
  CONSTRAINT com_fk FOREIGN KEY (city)
      REFERENCES "City" (city) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE "Company"
  OWNER TO postgres;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE "Company" TO postgres;
GRANT TRIGGER ON TABLE "Company" TO public;
GRANT TRIGGER ON TABLE "Company" TO public;


CREATE TRIGGER 'company_t' AFTER INSERT ON 'Company'
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE tfunc ();

  CREATE FUNCTION tfunc () RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
    BEGIN
      DELETE FROM Company
      WHERE com_id IN (SELECT com_id
                   FROM (SELECT com_id
                         row_number() over (partition BY com_name, city ORDER BY com_id) AS rnum
                     FROM Company) t
              WHERE t.rnum > 1);
    END;
    $$language plpgsql;
```

However, I got this error message:

[image]

So my questions are:
1. If my code can fulfill the function required. 
2. If my code are not correct, how can I fix it.

Any help?

Comment: `'company_t'` is a string literal, not an identifier. Identifiers are either not quoted at all (which I *highly* recommend to do!) or quoted using double quotes `"` (as you have did in the `create table` statement - which I would discourage you from doing). More details on identifiers are in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS